# Доступ к 1 файлу из нескольких источников

Tags: c#, .net, файлы, wcf, потоки-данных

Есть WCF служба, которая передает файлы клиенту.

Можно ли сделать так, что бы 2 и более клиента получили Stream на 1 файл и скачали его?

Если нет, то как , обычно, обходятся такие ограничения?

На ум приходит очередь на скачку и создание экземпляров одного и того же файла.

Есть что-нибудь еще?

Comment: Только на чтение? Без проблем по идее, никаких ограничений быть не должно.

Comment: А можно пример? Пробовал стримить один и тот же файл и ругается на занятость другим процессом.

Comment: А как вы создавали Stream? Может, вы открывали его на полный доступ?

Comment: Что-то типа `new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read)` должно быть.

Comment: @VladD, исходя из другого вопроса автора, он просто не закрывал stream после его создания,

Comment: @koks_rs: Ну, это не должно быть проблемой, если стрим открыт только на чтение. То есть это проблема, конечно (перерасход памяти), но не должна вести к вылету.